# Reload Jquery-ui multiselects

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-multiselect

I'm trying to call the uncheck all programatically:

```
$("#myDropdown").multiselect("uncheckall");
```

and it's not working.

How can I do the uncheckAll?

Comment: There is no such thing as `Jquery-ui multiselect`. Which plugin exactly are you using?

Comment: This one: http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is not good for this plugin:

I found a previous issue: https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/issues/556

You just need to use "uncheckAll" instead "uncheckall"

```
$("#myDropdown").multiselect("uncheckAll");
```